# Not remove folder but files removed

Tags: 14.10

Delete all the files in the work project, but do not delete the work directory, use the interactive option with –r (check the manual of rm command to do so)

Comment: Unless this is a new question. You should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/990346/edit) you original question, then [flag it for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Then delete this question if it is a duplicate.

Comment: This question i need the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not remove folder but sub directors or files removed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990346/not-remove-folder-but-sub-directors-or-files-removed)

Answer (score 2):

To keep the directory structure but remove just the regular files run.
`find /tmp/work -type f -delete`

To interactively remove both directories and files run.
`rm /tmp/work/* -irv`
The 'i' flag will make rm ask for permission for each removal. The 'r' flag will tell rm to recursively remove files. The 'v' flag makes rm tell you what it is doing.

```bash
# use brace expansion to create three levels of directories. The -p flag tells mkdir to create parent directories as needed.
mkdir -p /tmp/work/dir_{A..D}/dir_{a,b}
# tree will show the directory structure.
tree /tmp/work
/tmp/work
├── dir_A
│   ├── dir_a
│   └── dir_b
├── dir_B
│   ├── dir_a
│   └── dir_b
├── dir_C
│   ├── dir_a
│   └── dir_b
└── dir_D
    ├── dir_a
    └── dir_b
# For testing create empty files in each dir_a
touch /tmp/work/dir_{A..D}/dir_a/test.txt
# to Find what files will be deleted
find /tmp/work -type f
/tmp/work/dir_B/dir_a/test.txt
/tmp/work/dir_D/dir_a/test.txt
/tmp/work/dir_C/dir_a/test.txt
/tmp/work/dir_A/dir_a/test.txt  

# if the correct files were found now run the command but include the delete flag
find /tmp/work -type f -delete
# if however you would prefer to remove both files and the directories interactively. The 'i' flag will make rm ask for permission for each removal. The 'r' flag will tell rm to recursively remove files. The 'v' flag makes rm tell you what it is doing.
rm /tmp/work/* -irv
```

Comment: Does `-print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f` provide any advantage over simply `-delete`?

Comment: @steeldriver Some environments including cygwin may still not support the delete flag. But mostly I forgot to switch it after trying to get `rm` with a piped input to be interactive.

Comment: @steeldriver This is obviously a homework question as the user asked the same question again after it [was closed already](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990346/not-remove-folder-but-sub-directors-or-files-removed), so the `-print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f ` will allow the teacher to look for this particular answer on google too. **:-)**